# Coefficient of $x^4y^3z^3$ in the expansion of $(5x+y-4z)^{10}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

The coefficient of $x^6y^4$ in the expansion of $(2x-3y)^{10}$ is

$$_{10}C_6 \cdot 2^6 \cdot (-3)^4$$

and as for the coefficient of $x^3y^4z^8$ in the expansion of $(x+y+z)^{15}$ is

$$_{15}C_3 \cdot _{15}C_4 \cdot _{15}C_8 = \frac{15!}{3!4!8!} $$

What would be the the coefficient if the case would be $x^4y^3z^3$ in the expansion of $(5x+y-4z)^{10}$

Thank You

With Respect Umer Selmani

Comment: yeah , but i didnt know how to write that way, sorry

Comment: Well, I didn't even know that writing $_{10}C_6$ was possible! Try `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: Thank You! I'll do it next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that by [trinomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion)

$$(5x+y-4z)^{10} =\ldots+\frac{10!}{4!3!3!} (5x)^4y^3(-4z)^3+\ldots$$

therefore the coefficient for $x^4y^3z^3$ is equal to $-\frac{10!5^34^3}{4!3!3!}$.